# running median algorithm using counting select (C++)

Tags: c++, select, counting, median

I'm trying to implement a running median algorithm using counting select and have got stuck.

The sequence to be analysed is called 'mySequence' and I have created 2 global variables; vectors of data and counts. Data is what mySequence gets transferred to one by one and counts is the count of each element.

I fear I may have got this completely wrong or an missing an important step.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int maximum = 0;
vector<int> data;
vector<int> counts;
vector<int>::iterator it;

/*
 * A Program that calculates and outputs the running median of a sequence of values
 */

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function prints the running median of a sequence of values past to it
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void runningMedian(int element, int k) { // vector<int> &data
    maximum = data.size(); // finds how many data elements are to be processed  

    for (int i = 0; i <= maximum; i++) // this creates the counts for each element
    {
        counts[element] += 1;
    }

    int c = 0;
    while (k >= 0) {
        k -= counts[c++];
        }
    cout << c - 1;

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This main function uses test data to test the above functions
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int mySequence [] = {7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9}; // test sequence
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) counts.push_back(0); // This initialises the counts vector all to 0

    /// prints out the sequence of the data ///
    cout << "Sequence: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << mySequence[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    /// /// /// /// ///


    cout << "Running Medians: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data.push_back(mySequence[i]); // puts sequence into vector 1 by 1
        runningMedian(mySequence[i], (data.size() / 2));
        cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried by best up till this point.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mistake:

```
void runningMedian(int element, int k) { // vector<int> &data
    maximum = data.size(); // finds how many data elements are to be processed  

    for (int i = 0; i <= maximum; i++) // this creates the counts for each element
    {
        counts[element] += 1;
    }
```

I get worried when I see a `for` loop iterate `i=0; i<= ...` -- that will actually iterate through `maximum+1` times, not `maximum` times. (Idiomatic is `i=0; i< ...`.) This is often a fast route to a buffer overflow or uninitialized memory access -- but since you're not even using `i` in this case, it can't have that impact. I presume you meant `i` instead of `element` -- otherwise why even bother with the loop? This could be re-written without the loop like this:

```
counts[element] += (maximum + 1);
```

(You can see why I think you probably meant to use `i` as an array index.)

Nothing else stands out to me, but perhaps I've overlooked it too.

Comment: oh, that was it!
I hadn't removed the loop from when the code processed all elements together!
Thank you, thank you!